# What is the math behind increased savings leading to decreased interest rates?

Tags: supply-and-demand

In a general commodity market, if it's easier to produce, i.e. Marginal Cost decreases,
then producers will produce more and at a lower price, as the optimal quantity is at MC = MR and MR is always downward sloping.

In the money market, people saving more (putting more money into the bank) just gives banks more money to loan out. I understand that in order to sell the extra money, they need to lower price, but

1. what's the math behind it?
2. Also, is there a connection between the interest rate banks charge to the firms they lend to and the customers who deposit money into them? What's the math here?